# @Html.HiddenFor for timestamp is raising an error The input is not a valid Base-64 string

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, hidden-field

I have added a `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.timestamp)` to my asp.net mvc view. but after submitting the view i am recieving the following error

```
The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters. 

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

so what might be the problem ,, baring in mind that i have followed the same approach of adding `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.timestamp)` to my other views that represents other models and they worked fine.
the whole view which is causing the error looks as follow:-

```
@model Medical.Models.Patient

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>
@section scripts{
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>}

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Patient</legend>

            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PatientID)
           @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.timestamp)

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FatherName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FatherName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FatherName)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ThirdName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ThirdName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ThirdName)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FamilyName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FamilyName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FamilyName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NationalityID, "Country")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownList("NationalityID", String.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NationalityID)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GenderID, "Gender")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownList("GenderID", String.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GenderID)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Weight)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Weight)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Weight)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Height)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Height)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Height)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RegisterDate)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">

                 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RegisterDate , new { value = "FL", disabled = "disabled" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RegisterDate)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Telephone)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Telephone)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Telephone)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
            </div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.timestamp)
            <p>
              @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PatientID)
              @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RegisterDate)
                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    }

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
```

**:::--UPDATED--:::**

Here is the model partial class:-

```
namespace Medical.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(Patient_Validation))]
    [Bind(Exclude = "Country,Gender,Visits")]
    public partial class Patient
    {}}
```

and the model validation:-

```
public class Patient_Validation
    {
       [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:f}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
       [Display(Name = "Register Date")]
       public double RegisterDate { get; set; }

       [Timestamp]
       public Byte[] timestamp { get; set; }

       //[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:f}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
       [Display(Name = "Date Of Birth")]
       public double DateOfBirth { get; set; }

       [StringLength(50,MinimumLength=2)]
       [Display(Name = "First Name")]
       [MaxWords(10)]
       public string FirstName { get; set; }

         [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 2)]
         [Display(Name = "Father Name")]
         [MaxWords(10)]
       public string FatherName { get; set;} 

          [StringLength(50,MinimumLength=2)]
          [Display(Name = "Third Name")]
          [MaxWords(10)]
       public string ThirdName { get; set; }

         [StringLength(50,MinimumLength=2)]
         [Display(Name = "Family Name")]
         [MaxWords(10)]
       public string FamilyName { get; set; 
 [Required(ErrorMessage= "Gender is Required")]
        [Display(Name = "Gender")]
        public int GenderID { get; set; }

        [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}",ErrorMessage="Please Insert Valid Email Address")]

        public string Email { get; set; }
```

Comment: could you show us the model please

Comment: I UPDATE MY ORIGINAL POST WITH THE MODEL CLASS. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Html.Serialize for byte arrays.

Check out this link on the HTML.Serialize helper:

http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/07/26/using-the-features-of-asp-net-mvc-3-futures.aspx

Comment: but why did the byte[] time stamp worked well on another view that represents other models